# Can't see microphone request popup on Iphone

Tags: flutter

I run this line of code: `final status = await Permission.microphone.request();`

But I always get `PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied` without a microphone request popup, and in the iPhone settings the microphone is not in the list at all.

`Info.plist` has `<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>`

and in `Podfile` is `'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1'`,

What else do I need to make this work?